# What is the most efficient way to repartition a data frame with the following constraints?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, time-series, rdd

I have a time series dataframe stored at one partition

```
+-------------+------+----+-------+
|    TimeStamp|     X|   Y|      Z|
+-------------+------+----+-------+
|1448949705421|-35888|4969|3491754|
|1448949705423|-35081|2795|3489177|
|1448949705425|-35976|5830|3488618|
|1448949705426|-36927|4729|3491807|
|1448949705428|-36416|6246|3490364|
|1448949705429|-36073|7067|3491556|
|1448949705431|-38553|3714|3489545|
|1448949705433|-39008|3034|3490230|
|1448949705434|-35295|4005|3489426|
|1448949705436|-36397|5076|3490941|
+-------------+------+----+-------+
```

I want to repartition this dataframe into 10 partitions, such that the first partition has roughly the first 1/10 rows, the second partition has roughly the second 1/10 rows, and so on.

One way I can think of is:

```
var df = ???
// add index to df
val rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(indexedRow =>
            Row.fromSeq(indexedRow._2.toLong +: indexedRow._1.toSeq))
val newstructure = StructType(Seq(StructField("rn", LongType, true)).++(df.schema.fields))
val dfWithIndex = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, newstructure)

// create a group number using the index
val udfToInt = udf[Int, Double](_.toInt)
val dfWithGrp = dfWithIndex.withColumn("group", udfToInt($"rn" / (df.count / 10)))

// repartition by the "group" column
val partitionedDF = dfWithGrp.repartition(10, $"group")
```

Another way I can think of is by using a partitioner:

```
//After creating a group number
val grpIndex = dfWithGrp.schema.fields.size - 1
val partitionedRDD = dfWithGrp.rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(grpIndex), r))
    .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10))
    .values
```

But they seem to be not efficient because we need to add index first and then create a group number using the index. Is there a way to do this without adding an extra group column?

Comment: Why not use timestamp as index, assuming it would be unique. Mostly the index is to make sure you get unique values for the grouping

Comment: @Ramzy But using timestamp as index requires that there is no big jump on the timestamp between adjacent rows. The timestamp may look like "1, 3, 4, 5, 1001, 1002, 1004 ..."